# Loading jquery at the end with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sharepoint

Hi all iam new to jquery and angularjs(have done jquery for validations in .net apps but not much exp so please bear with me)
i want my jquery code to run at last after angular js below is my controller class
what i need is on hover i have to show the submenu (this is done through jquery)
i tried with this "viewContentLoaded" but still no luck 
jquery function is called on ready but its laoding first before my controller data

```
var MenuCtrl = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', '$location', '$route', 'Data', function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $location, $route, Data) {

    $scope.menu = Data;

    $scope.selected = 0;
    $scope.setSelected = function (index) {

        $scope.selected = index;
    };

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        alert('loaded');
    });

}];

**My HTML -Angular**
 <section ng-repeat="m in menu track by $index">
                    <section class="item">
                         <div class="item-destinations" ">
                            <a ng-href="{{m.PageURL}}">{{m.Title}}-{{$index}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </section>

**My jquery**

$('.item-destinations').hover(
        function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.navExpand').stop().animate({
                top: "63"
            }, 300, function () {
                destMenuOpen = true;
            });
        },
        function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, jQuery is attaching the `hover` event handler before Angular is done adding the elements to the DOM. Use `jQuery.on()` to attach an event handler further up the DOM to listen for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on `.item-destinations` via propagation...

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.navExpand').stop().animate({
            top: "63"
        }, 300, function () {
            destMenuOpen = true;
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, '.item-destinations');
```

Also consider encapsulating this behavior in an angular directive.

Comment: Hi Anthony,    Thanks for your answer i will include it in directive